# Programmatically Sort Start Menu

Tags: c#, windows, sorting

I'm looking to sort the start menu alphabetically using C#. I've read about deleting the registry key

`HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MenuOrder`

but when I tried it on my machine it doesn't appear to do much of anything. Does anyone have any other ideas as to what must be done in order to sort the Start Menu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, you can't, and it's on purpose.

From Raymond Chen's blog (good read for Windows developers):

> Because the power would be used for
>   evil far more than it would be used
>   for good.

Full entry [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2006/06/19/636823.aspx).